# Running KMeans clustering several times with the same random seed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, random-seed

I have a problem with understanding the scikit-learn specification of the KMeans clustering function. The function:
`sklearn.cluster.k_means(X, n_clusters, *, sample_weight=None, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, verbose=False, tol=0.0001, random_state=None, copy_x=True, algorithm='lloyd', return_n_iter=False)`.
The specification says that:

- `init{‘k-means++’, ‘random’}, callable or array-like of shape (n_clusters, n_features), default=’k-means++’`
  Method for initialization:
  'k-means++' : selects initial cluster centers for k-mean clustering in a smart way to speed up convergence. See section Notes in k_init for more details.
- `n_init int, default=10`
  Number of time the k-means algorithm will be run with different centroid seeds. The final results will be the best output of n_init consecutive runs in terms of inertia.
- `random_state int, RandomState instance or None, default=None`
  Determines random number generation for centroid initialization. Use an int to make the randomness deterministic.

**The question:**

If I run the algorithm with `init = k-means++, n_init = 10 and random_state = int (0, 1, 42 etc.)` will it mean that: (1) the algorithm will be run 10 times with the same initial cluster centers; (2) the inital cluster centers will be different for each run (but still determined by the random number generator associated with the specified random state) or (3) for each of the 10 runs the inital cluster centers will be different because they will be determined by different seeds? I am little confused because to me it seems like the `n_init` is contradictory to setting a `random_state`.

Comment: The document says that n_init is `Number of time the k-means algorithm will be run with different centroid seeds. The final results will be the best output of n_init consecutive runs in terms of inertia.`  So the function finds the best result by running the k-means procedure n_init times. They start with different initial cluster. You will have the identical start clusters if you set the same random_state.

Comment: @KotaMori so (if I understand correctly) the n_init doesn't matter when the random_state is set. But still, there is the max_iter paramter - here, for each iteration the initial cluster centers will change (they will be 'selected' from the same random number generator determined by random seed but they will not be the same every time) or not?

Comment: @skav_ no, the kmeans algorithm works differently. the randomized initialization is determined by a provided random state or seed. if it is provided you should get reproducible results. the max_iter property is for the (change of) centroid setting after initialization. see official docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans